# Cannot create abstract class in codemodel?

Tags: sun-codemodel

My code:

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
cm._class(JMod.ABSTRACT, "TestClass", ClassType.CLASS);
cm.build(new File("."));
```

no matter what I write to `mods` or `ClassType` parameter, the outcome is always a `public class`.

How can I create an abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange.  It seems JCodeModel doesn't create abstract classes without a package.  The following cases have a package declaration:

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
cm._class(JMod.PUBLIC | JMod.ABSTRACT, "test.TestClass", ClassType.CLASS);
cm.build(new File("."));
```

Generates:

```
package test;

public abstract class TestClass {

}
```

or

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
JPackage pkg = cm._package("");
pkg._class(JMod.ABSTRACT, "TestClass2", ClassType.CLASS);
cm.build(new File("."));
```

Generates:

```
public abstract class TestClass2 {

}
```